# finding most authors in a sparql query

Tags: sparql, rdf

I want to create a SPARQL query that shows the author with the most books and also author who has more than one creator for their books.
Can I please have help?

Comment: so, htisis homework I guess? what about reading a SPARQL tutorial first? Where can we see your first tries? Where can we see the data? You know, I'm asking because the idea is that people show the efforts first and they also provide enough information. Otherwise, you need grouping with aggregate function `count`, grouping has to be done by author. For the second task you can make use of `having` clause then - pretty sure you'll find the solution, and don't forget to post it here as an answer

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had included my code in, I know this is incorrect - I know which functions house but i’m confused on how to execute query.                              PREFIX foaf:  <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
SELECT DISTINCT *
WHERE {
    ?person foaf:name ?name .
}
 group by ?person having (count(?name) > 2)

Comment: why do you think it is incorrect? `SELECT ?person WHERE { ?person foaf:name ?name . } group by ?person having (count(?name) >= 2) ` is the correct query.

Comment: and what means "how to execute"? Just use a SPARQL engine of your choice

Comment: The following query doesn’t show me the authors who have the most books, it shows me books that have more than one author. I want to be able find those who have the most books in the dataset, and then also find if they have more than 2 authors.

Comment: I was totally confused, why do you use `foaf:name`? you need the property between author and book. that'S the point where you should show your data here.

Comment: `SELECT ?person (count(?book) as ?cnt) WHERE { ?person ex:author ?book  } group by ?person order by desc(?cnt)`